# How to install npm packages in Ubuntu using WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have installed Ubuntu using WSL2.

Now in working directory `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\ponomarchukov\nodejs` I try to install npm packages:

```
npm install express
```

So, I get this error:

```
-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `npm` shell script you are using has a carriage return (Ctrl-M, ASCII 13) at the end.  On Unix systems, specifying a carriage return in a shell script is an error; your lines must end with line feeds only.  Even if you are using the bash version that comes with Git for Windows, this is the case as well.

You should figure out where you're getting your `npm` shell script from and fix it such that it does not contain carriage returns.  You may wish to do this with a program like `dos2unix`.  If you're seeing this because you checked it out with Git, read the `gitattributes` manual page to see more about how to set certain files to always have Unix line endings (`eol=lf`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually started WSL in the terminal you are using? Also, have you installed node/npm in Ubuntu? Looks like it is using npm from the Windows-installation. I can recommend [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), which has a simple install script - this is a download manager for node and allows easy install/update of node/npm on Linux.

Comment: I suggest using [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm) instead of nvm, because it doesn’t slow down shell startup.